# Using WYSIWYG In custom meta boxes

Tags: metabox, post-meta, wp-editor

So I've created a few meta boxes using the wp_editor, all are exactly as the following:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'business_facts_metabox' );              
function business_facts_metabox() 
    {   
        add_meta_box('business_facts', 'Business Facts', 'business_facts_output', 'page', 'normal', 'high');
    }

function business_facts_output( $post ) 
    {
    //so, dont ned to use esc_attr in front of get_post_meta
    $business_facts_value=  get_post_meta($_GET['post'], 'business_facts' , true ) ;
    wp_editor( htmlspecialchars_decode($business_facts_value), 'business-facts', $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'business-facts') );
    }


function save_business_facts( $post_id ) 
{                   
    if (!empty($_POST['business-facts']))
        {
        $data=htmlspecialchars($_POST['business-facts']);
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'business_facts', $data );
        }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_business_facts' );
```

Unfortunately, when I output what is saved, it outputs everything, so it doesn't show bolds, instead if I were to output a bold word, it would output <strong>word</strong>, instead of **word**. I need it to output properly with styling and html working properly.

Is this possible using custom metaboxes? if so, what do I need to edit in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured this out almost immediately after posting this question (duh)

```
function business_facts_output( $post ) 
    {
    //so, dont ned to use esc_attr in front of get_post_meta
    $business_facts_value=  get_post_meta($_GET['post'], 'business_facts' , true ) ;
    wp_editor( htmlspecialchars_decode($business_facts_value), 'business-facts', $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'business-facts') );
}
```

Basically this bit here, where it says `htmlspecialchars_decode($business_facts_value)` needs to be changed. the htmlspecialchars_decode() function isn't needed here, instead I just needed the $business_facts_value